# How do I write the following html class css structure in reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add a simple onhover tooltip to my reactjs card slider, which has the following css structure that I made using the w3schools editor. However, I cannot figure out how to write it correctly in reactjs project.

Here is the css I'm trying to add into my reactjs project

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  font-family: lato, sans-serif;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  transition: 1s;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">



<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

This is my reactjs card slider file.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ItemsCarousel from "react-items-carousel";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Img1 from "../assest/sliderImage/img1.png";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const ImgSlider = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeItemIndex, setActiveItemIndex] = useState(0);
  const chevronWidth = 60;
  return (
    <div className={classes.slideContainer}>
      <h2 className={classes.h2}>Browse popular categories</h2>
      <div className={classes.sliderBox}>
        <ItemsCarousel
          className={classes.ItemSlider}
          requestToChangeActive={setActiveItemIndex}
          activeItemIndex={activeItemIndex}
          numberOfCards={3}
          slidesToScroll={3}
          gutter={0} >
          <div className={classes.Img1}>
            <div className={classes.TextDiv}>
              <strong className={classes.title}>
                <imgclassName={classes.img} src={Img1} />
                <p>Plumber</p>
              </strong>
              <span>
                <span></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.Img1}>
            <div className={classes.TextDiv}>
              <strong className={classes.title}>
              <div className={classes.tooltip}>Hover over me
              <span className={classes.tooltiptext }>Tooltip text</span>
            </div>
                <img  className={classes.img} src={Img3} />
                <p >Remodeling</p>
              </strong>
              <span className={classes.price}>
                <span></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ItemsCarousel>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  );
};

export default ImgSlider;
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  slider: {
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      display: "none",
    },
    marginTop: "250px",
  },
  
  sliderBox: {
    overflowX: "none ",
    marginTop: "-40px",
    
  },
  serviceSlider: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
    TextDiv: {
    display: "flex",
    flexFlow: "column",
    height: "100%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    // paddingLeft: '32px',
    maxWidth: "170px",
  },
  title: {
    letterSpacing: "0.2px",
    display: "inline-block",
    marginBottom: "4px",
    fontSize: "16px",
    lineHeight: "24px",
    fontWeight: "400px",
    fontfamily: "latobold, sans-serif",
  },
  ItemSlider: {
    display: "grid",
    transation: "0.2s ease-in-out",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      transation: "0.2s ease-in-out",
    },
  },

  img: {
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xl")]: {
      width: "700px !important",
      borderRadius: "50px",
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down("lg")]: {
      width: "300px !important",
      borderRadius: "0px",
    },
    width: "300px",
  },
}));
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the complete react file and CSS file you are using inside that react project? Otherwise, it would be very hard to tell for anyone.

Comment: You could check the entire slidecard.js file right now. Thanks